# Concatenating Two ArrayLists Using = and += Instead of a For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have an arrayList arr3 and I am trying to concatenate two other arrayLists (arr1 and arr2) and then store them into arr3. I know you can use a for loop to do this; however, could could you also just use = and += in this case.

```
arr3 = arr1
arr3 += arr2;
```

As you can see, I have that written out just above. Is this valid? Or do you absolutely have to use a for loop.

Comment: Run your code and see what happens.

Comment: I can't this is a part 2 that needs to be done on paper.

Comment: You're at a computer right now.

Comment: The teacher controls all of the blue java programs that we can use in school, and disables them for a part 2 that is supposed to be writtten.

Comment: I can; however, use the internet and sites like stackoverflow that she has recommend to use

Comment: You need a different language for that (C++, C#).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thank you! Yes, I now know that as Eduardo Dennis just answered the question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot join two array lists with the += operator. You will just have to loop over one and add each value to the other.

or use the `addAll` method of the ar3 to add the array lists you want to add.

Comment: Thank you! That is just the straight forward answer that I was looking for

Comment: you're welcome. If you found it helpful please accept :)